# Internal Server Error right after installation of OpenERP 7.0

Tags: odoo, server-error

I am new at OpenERP and I just installed OpenERP 7.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 using the All-In-One ".deb" file. But when I tried to open it it gave me this error message:

> Internal Server Error: The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

I checked the "openerp-server.log" file and it gave me this:

```
    self.gen.next()
File "/usr/share/pyshared/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 422, in session_context
session_store.save(request.session)
File "/usr/share/pyshared/werkzeug/contrib/sessions.py", line 237, in savedir=self.path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 300, in mkstemp
return _mkstemp_inner(dir, prefix, suffix, flags)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 235, in _mkstemp_inner
fd = _os.open(file, flags, 0600)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission non accordée: '/tmp/oe-sessions-openerp/tmpNUQsbf.__wz_sess'
```

What is going wrong and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a permission issue. You can check permissions of your server/addons/web directory and change it's to Read/Write/Create/Delete like this

```
chmod 777 DIRPATH_OF_SERVER -R
chmod 777 DIRPATH_OF_ADDONS -R
chmod 777 DIRPATH_OF_WEB -R
```

By assigning all permissions, Can you re-check it ?